# Re-Instatement of a patent

Tags: us4461078

In reference to the patent: [US4461078](https://www.google.com/patents/US4461078)

Is it possible to get re-instated on a patent you received that annual renewal fees were not paid?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes yes, in this case the priority date is 1982, the normal patent duration is 20 years, if it has a patent term adjustment due to a slow application processing it can go up to 25. Both are over, so this patent is definitly not getting reinstated.

Comment: Are you sure a terminal disclaimer ADDS five years to the total life of the patent? I believe a terminal disclaimer aims to end the protection that the patent offers where there are claims with similar scope in another patent. A patent can gain more than 20 years of lifetime with the Patent Term Adjustment (PTA), as far as I know, due to delays during examination. In any case, you are right that the patent has PD 1982, so it is "dead" for good.

Comment: Wooops ... uhm ... ahhh ... I don't know what you are talking about, it clearly says pta, mixing those up would be rather stupid as the td substracts term duration. ... thx for noticing ;)

Comment: Btw, 1982 could be 17 years not 20 and/or max. PTA of 2 yrs, I dont remember when that changed. (1978?)

Comment: One has to learn a lot in this job ;)

Comment: To my defense, Europe doesn't have this ;)

Comment: I am European-based as well, I know how confusing this can be. Mind that the PTA extension is under 35 USC par. 154(b), BUT there is also the PTE extension under 35 USC par. 156. The latter is for drugs and resembles the European SPC. Take a look here, if you are more interested http://www.fr.com/files/Uploads/Maximizing%20Patent%20Term%20PowerPoint%20Presentation.pdf

Comment: I'll have a look, thx.